# Gitlab CI with CakePHP 3

Tags: php, gitlab, cakephp-3.0, gitlab-ci

I'm using CakePHP and want to benefit from CI using Gitlab. 
I have the config for [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1715725.js) with this in `config/app.php`:

```
/**
     * The test connection is used during the test suite.
     */
    'test' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => env('MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost'),
        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => env('MYSQL_USER', 'root'),
        'password' => env('MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD', 'mysql_strong_password'),
        'database' => env('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'test'),
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'log' => false,
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
        //'url' => env('DATABASE_TEST_URL', null),
    ],
```

But unfortunately, my tests are failing permanently.

> .Exception: Unable to insert fixtures for "App\Test\TestCase\Controller\CategoriesControllerTest" test case. SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in [/builds/koffisani/gabways-web/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureManager.php, line 358]
>   ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

I need a little help to progress.

### Update :

Gitlab CI config :

```
image: kaffineaddict/gitlabcakephp3

# Cache the vendor folder
cache:
  paths:
  - vendor/


before_script:
# Install git to clone your repository
- apt-get update -yqq
- apt-get install git libcurl4-gnutls-dev libicu-dev libmcrypt-dev libvpx-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev libxml2-dev libexpat1-dev libbz2-dev libgmp3-dev libldap2-dev unixodbc-dev libpq-dev libsqlite3-dev libaspell-dev libsnmp-dev libpcre3-dev libtidy-dev -yqq
- docker-php-ext-install mbstring mcrypt pdo_mysql curl json intl gd xml zip bz2 opcache

# Install composer
- curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

# Install all project dependencies
- composer install

services:
- mysql

variables:
  # Configure mysql service (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
  # We will need to use these in the app.php test datasource
  MYSQL_DATABASE: test_myapp
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret

# Run the phpunit tests
All:
 script:
  - cp config/app.default.php app.php
  - vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: With this little information its hard to help. Does your general deployment work? How does your gitlab-ci.yml looks like? I guess there is no database to connect to...

Comment: Thank @TobiasGaertner, I updated the question.

Comment: Have you set the env-variables "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" and "MYSQL_DATABASE"? If not it fails because the defaul values "mysql_strong_password" and "test" are not matching the settings in your gitlab-ci.yml.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasGaertner. but, do I need any other setting than in the Gitlab CI file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured it out.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file contains this block :

```
variables:
# Configure mysql service (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)
# We will need to use these in the app.php test datasource
   MYSQL_DATABASE: test
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql_strong_password
   MYSQL_HOST: mysql
```

And the `app.php` data structure section is as follows :

```
'test' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'mysql',
        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'mysql_strong_password',
        'database' => 'test',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'log' => false,
        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
        'url' => env('DATABASE_TEST_URL', null),
    ],
```

And things went well. It may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

So in your .gitlab-ci.yml file you define a mysql-service-container with

```
database: test_myapp
password: secret
user: root (this is default)
```

In your config/app.php you define a test database the test should use like:

```
'username' => env('MYSQL_USER', 'root'),
'password' => env('MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD', 'mysql_strong_password'),
'database' => env('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'test'),
```

So you either have to define the env-variables (MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DATABASE) somewhere (that's possible in the gitlab pipelines settings for your project) or you set the default values matching the database settings from your .gitlab-ci.yml.